# How do I store a fetch response to a derived store in svelte?

Tags: fetch, store, svelte

I have a list of items which I consume from an own custom built API (in the example I'll use typicode) and want to display them. Additionally I want to add a client side search functionality. It is exactly like this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a86d6f3df7b41f69f0fc93ba1ad0fd3?version=3.31.2) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616230/11160383).

But the given list is hardcoded, yet I can't seem to build a fetch call to get those items prior and afterwards display them. Only then can the user search and filter them.

Here is my [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/39a47d1328c141e8b051196fa5fa8b98?version=3.45.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, so you should `await` it.

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/a93ac2dcff584b2f8d11e430c6a96fa9?version=3.31.2